# Do I need to import submodules directly?

Tags: python, import

Let's say I have a module `foo` and a submodule `foo.bar`. If I want to use a method in `foo.bar`, do I need to import `foo.bar` directly or is importing `foo` sufficient?

For example, the following throws an error:

```
import foo

foo.bar.my_method()
```

and the following works:

```
import foo.bar

foo.bar.my_method()
```

But I'm not sure if this is generally what's needed, or if there's something wrong with my code itself. (I would think importing the submodule directly is generally needed... But I could have sworn I've seen code where it's not imported directly and still works fine.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> If I want to use a method in `foo.bar`, do I need to import `foo.bar` directly or is importing `foo` sufficient?

You'll need to import the submodule explicitly.  Executing `import foo.bar` will automatically import the parent module `foo`, and necessarily<sup>†</sup> bind the name `foo`, but the reverse is not true.

> But I could have sworn I've seen code where it's not imported directly and still works fine

Yes.  Sometimes accessing a submodule works without the explicit import.  This happens when a parent module itself imports the submodules.  Never rely on that unless it's documented, because it may be an implementation detail and could change without warning after a library version upgrade.

As an example of a popular library which demonstrates *both* behaviors, look at `requests==2.18.4`.  This package has submodules called `sessions` and `help` (amongst others).  Importing `requests` will make `requests.sessions` available implicitly, yet `requests.help` will not be available until explicitly imported.  You'll find when the source code of the package init is executed that [the `sessions` submodule gets imported](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/v2.18.4/requests/__init__.py#L101), but the `help` submodule does not.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>This makes sense, because subsequent use of `foo.bar` requires an attribute access on an existing `foo` object.  Note that `from foo.bar import something` does *not* bind the name `foo` nor `foo.bar`, though both modules `foo` and `foo.bar` are imported and cached into `sys.modules`.</sub>

Comment: Oh, super helpful, thanks! In the [`__init__.py` you linked to](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/v2.18.4/requests/__init__.py#L101), what's the reason for `from .sessions import session, Session` if those imports aren't used in the `__init__.py` file directly? Just to make it so that importing `requests.sessions` isn't absolutely necessary?

Comment: This is likely a convenience - pulling names up into the parent namespace.  Library users can now write an import statement `from requests import Session`, that's shorter yet equivalent to `from requests.sessions import Session`.