# Why can't I use module in python imported as alias in another import statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Why do I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'` for:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tf.keras.models
```

doesn't Python reference `tf` as an alias to `tensorflow` from the line `import tensorflow as tf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using with `tensorflow`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.models
```

Or you can use it as

```
import tensorflow as tf
sys.modules['tf'] = tensorflow
import tf.keras.models
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

it has already imported all the sub-modules as tensorflow is a package.

So, to get the models, you just need to access it, no need to import

```
tf.keras.models
```

If you wanna import a specific module, then,

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
```

Comment: Are you sure? according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641621/do-i-need-to-import-submodules-directly , I should import each submodule explicitly.

Comment: You need to import specific submodule explicitly if you only use that submodule.