# module 'scipy.sparse' has no attribute 'linalg'

Tags: python, scipy, python-import

While working anaconda spyder, I have this weird behavior with the package `scipy`.

[image]

The first time I tried to use `sparse.linalg`, I get an error:

> AttributeError: module 'scipy.sparse' has no attribute 'linalg'

However, I was able to load linalg with `from scipy.sparse import linalg`. And after this, the above error doesn't appear again.

Comment: I this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641621/do-i-need-to-import-submodules-directly/49641638#49641638) post answers your question