# Python 2 boto: key attribute

Tags: python, boto

I could have sworn I used this before and it was working fine.  Not sure if my environment changed or I am forgetting something else.

```
import boto

b = "some_bucket"
key = "some_s3_key"

k = boto.s3.key.Key(b, key)
```

but now I am getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Am I doing something wrong?  This is for

```
boto            2.49.0
botocore        1.16.7
```

with python 2

I was going to use `k.get_file()` and `k.set_contents_from_file()`

Answer (score 2):

In general it's required to [import submodules directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49641621/674039).

Instead of

```
import boto
```

Use

```
import boto.s3.key
```

Please note that boto has been [deprecated for quite some time](https://github.com/boto/boto/#deprecation-notice), the last release was in 2018 and this project is no longer maintained.

You should consider switching over to [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3).

Comment: Ok, thanks that woks.  Yea I know, I wish.  Its a legacy environment and its not easy to update the env (and I dont have rights to :( )