# Module name binding by relative import in __init__.py

Tags: python

I wrote a package containing two submodules:

```
pkg/__init__.py
pkg/foo.py
pkg/bar.py
```

I put the following code in `__init__.py` and also in `bar.py`.

```py
from . import foo as f
foo
print("Hello!")
```

While importing `pkg` suceeds, `pkg.bar` doesn't:

```
>>> import pkg
Hello!

>>> import pkg.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\fumito\Documents\pkg\bar.py", line 2, in <module>
    foo
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Why is `foo` defined in the `pkg` namespace but not in the `pkg.bar`?

Comment: From which directory are you executing your python interpreter ?

Comment: The directory where pkg is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. I think this is one of the best answers on this topic:
[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/10908183) Don't worry - importing in python is a bit convoluted.

Comment: @BlockFace The answer from there is fine, but the question is very clearly not a duplicate. You could write an answer summarizing the relevant points from that answer and linking there

Comment: Related: [Do I need to import submodules directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49641638/674039)

Comment: This is explained in the docs at [*5.4.2 Submodules*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By importing the `foo` module, it implicitly becomes an attribute of `pkg`, because its fully qualified location is `pkg.foo`. This makes the name `foo` available in `__init__.py`, because it became an attribute of `pkg`/`__init__.py`.

But obviously, `pkg.bar.foo` would make no sense, since that's not the fully qualified name of the `foo` module, so importing `foo` in `bar` does *not* create a name `foo` inside `bar`.

(This is a rather handwavey explanation, but summarises the core mechanism at play here.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I couldn't find the behaviour in the language reference, but based on your explanation, I understand that the name `foo` is bound at the time when the foo module is imported. And I checked this is also true when `pkg` is given as an absolute path, i.e.  `from pkg import foo as f` in `__init__.py`

Comment: The docs reference is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules). This answer leaves a lot to be desired: .py files don't have attributes, module instances do. It would also have been possible for the import system to leave `pkg.foo` in `sys.modules` _without_ additionally adding `foo` into the `pkg.__dict__`. "Fully qualified locations" have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score -3):

**EDIT : This answer is incorrect. Please read the explanation in the next section.**

It is because when you try to import the modules when you are in the same directory as `pkg`, the relative import happens from where `pkg` is. That means that the following statement in `bar.py`

```
from . import foo as f
```

attempts to find `foo` in the parent directory of `pkg`.

You could choose to write the following import statement in `pkg/bar.py` instead (I personally prefer this method because it doesn't modify the path)

```
import pkg.foo as f
```

Or you could choose to modify the path variable within your `__init__.py` file

```
import os, sys

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(script_dir)
```

And then, add the following import statement in `bar.py`

```
import foo as f
```

===============================================================
**ATTEMPT 2**

So [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76564786/10908183) has provided a really nice answer which I will try to expand upon.

What you are doing is quite similar to what is stated in the Python docs in [5.4.2. Submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. `importlib` APIs, the `import` or `import-from` statements, or built-in `__import__()`) a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the submodule. Let’s say you have the following directory structure:

```
spam/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
```

> and `spam/__init__.py` has the following line in it:

```
from .foo import Foo
```

> then executing the following puts name bindings for `foo` and `Foo` in the `spam` module:

```
>>>import spam
>>>spam.foo
<module 'spam.foo' from '/tmp/imports/spam/foo.py'>
>>>spam.Foo
<class 'spam.foo.Foo'>
```

> Given Python’s familiar name binding rules this might seem surprising, but it’s actually a fundamental feature of the import system. The invariant holding is that if you have `sys.modules['spam']` and `sys.modules['spam.foo']` (as you would after the above import), the latter must appear as the `foo` attribute of the former.

Similar to what is mentioned in the docs, when you add the statement

```py
# pkg/__init__.py

from . import foo as f
foo
print("Hello!")
```

in `__init__.py` and then import `pkg`, `pkg.foo` exists because of the import statement, which is why `NameError` is not raised. Therefore, importing `pkg` will be successful. You can check that `pkg.foo` is referring to `foo.py` if you check the value of `pkg.foo` within the terminal - you will see a similar return value to

```
<module 'pkg.foo' from 'absolute/path/to/pkg/foo.py'>
```

Now adding the following code in `bar.py`

```py
# pkg/bar.py

from . import foo as f
foo
print("Hello!")
```

and attempting to execute

```py
import pkg.bar
```

does raise the `NameError` exception because an object `foo` does not exist within `bar.py`; `foo` does not exist within the namespace of `bar.py`.

There is something interesting that is also happening when you used an alias to import `foo` within `__init__.py`. It is actually possible to overwrite the reference `pkg.foo` while still maintaining access to the contents of `foo.py`. If you added the following block within your `__init__.py` file after `foo`

```py
class foo:
    pass
```

then checking the reference `pkg.foo` will return

```
<class 'pkg.foo'>
```

but contents of `foo.py` can still be accessed by using `pkg.f`. If you check the value of `pkg.f`, you will see someting similar to

```
<module 'pkg.foo' from 'absolute/path/to/pkg/foo.py'>
```

Comment: If the way of importing was the problem, then you'd get an `ImportError` on the `import` line, not a `NameError` on the next line.

Comment: @deceze you're right. I must have misread the question.