# can I control setuptools imports more finely?

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools

I'm having some difficulty controlling precisely which modules of my package are being imported by `setuptools`. It seems to be importing "greedily" and I don't know why.

Let's say I have the following (flat) code structure:

```
tstpkg/
  pyproject.toml
  tstpkg/
    __init__.py
    modA
      fnA1
      fnA2
    modB
      fnB1
      fnB2
    modC
      fnC1
      fnC2
```

and let's imagine I want to have *only* `tstpkg.fnA1()` and `tstpkg.fnC2()` available to me after I import `tstpkg`. My expectation is that if `pyproject.toml` includes

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
namespaces = false
```

and if `__init__.py` includes

```
from tstpkg.modA import fnA1
from tstpkg.modC import fnC2
```

then I should be all set. But this makes the entire `tstpkg.modA` and `tstpkg.modC` available when I install and import `tstpkg`, which is not what I would like.

I have found that I can add `del(modA, modC)` to `__init__.py`, but I find this a bit inelegant. And it's confusing, because if I (for instance) boot up `ipython` and simply do `from scipy.special import gammaln as sgl` I don't have all of `scipy.special` available to me.

Two questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. And is there any natural way to get the behavior that I am after?

Comment: FYI, this questions seems to have nothing to do with setuptools or distributions. This just has to do with how imports work, and when/how attributes get added to module objects (for submodule objects and otherwise)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to import submodules directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641621/do-i-need-to-import-submodules-directly)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "if I do from `scipy.special import gammaln as sgl` I don't have all of `scipy.special` available to me". If you run that import, there _will_ be a `special` attribute added to the `scipy` module object, which you can access all of `scipy.special` from. Are you maybe refering to the fact that `from a.b.c import d` imports don't bind a variable `a` to the module object for `a`?

Comment: when I do `from scipy.special import gammaln as sgl`, and then `scipy.special?` I get an error: ```Object `scipy.special` not found.``` but `sgl?` provides the full documentation, as expected (and described in the question). So I do *not* seem to be replicating the behavior described in the answer to the question you linked, actually (in which it says "Executing `import foo.bar` will automatically import the parent module `foo`, and necessarily bind the name `foo`")

Comment: `from a.b.c import  d` is not the same as `import a`, since the former doesn't assign to a variable named `a`, only to `d`. The problem is that you're trying to use the _variable_ `scipy` with actually assigning to it first. Just write `scipy` on it own, and you'll get a `NameError`. What's still true is that after `from scipy.special import ...`, both the modules `scipy` and `scipy.special` did get imported, and a `special` attribute was added to the `scipy` module object. You just don't have a variable that reference the `scipy` module object yet.

Comment: If you access the `scipy` module in any way (e.g., `import scipy`, `sys.modules['scipy']`, `__import__("scipy")`, etc), you'll see the module object does have a `special` attribute, which reference `<module 'scipy.special' from '...'>`

Comment: Is your goal that `tstpkg.modA`/`tstpkg.modC` shouldn't be accessed directly at all (maybe you only want uses to use the named re-exported in `__init__.py`)? If so, you can mark those submodules are private/implementation details by prefixing them with an underscore. You'll still get `_modA`/`_modC` attributes on the `tskpkg` module the moment they're imported, but they are least won't be "public"

Comment: I'm trying to make the namespace of `tstpkg` as uncluttered as possible (which isn't a concern in this simple example, but becomes one in my actual case of interest with more modules in the package), so I don't want to have `tstpkg.modA` available upon doing `import tstpkg`, similar to how `scipy.special` is not available when I do `from scipy.special import gammaln`, which I thought should be doable by proper arrangement of `pyproject.toml` and `__init__.py`. And, yes, I understand that I can hide those modules in the manner you describe. But I'm just confused by the default behavior